# Calling coffescript super methods

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
    class Animal
        constructor: (@name) -> 
        say: () -> console.log "Hello from animal called #{ @name }"

    class Dog extends Animal

        say: () ->
            super.say()
            console.log "Hello from dog called #{ @name }"

    a = new Animal('Bobby')
    a.say()

    d = new Dog("Duffy")
    d.say()
```

The result is not

```
Hello from animal called Bobby
Hello from animal called Duffy
Hello from dog called Duffy
```

But I get the following error:

```
Hello from animal called Bobby
Hello from animal called Duffy
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'say' of undefined
```

How come super is undefined? How to call a parent method in order to extend it? Thanks

Comment: Your guess was my guess... makes me wonder why they didn't just make it work like practically everyone guesses it should? Maybe an interesting discussion

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I found the answer myself, it should be:

```
class Dog extends Animal

    say: () ->
        super
        console.log "Hello from dog called #{ @name }"
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `super()`?

Comment: @Ryan_IRL you don't need to use `()` when calling super. The compiler can tell that when you use the `super` keyword you are invoking the function.

Comment: We should be able to put arguments through as well I suppose.

Comment: @Ziyan - if the base method takes an argument, you can pass it: `super("woof")`.

Comment: How would you call super if you are using fat arrow (=>)?

Comment: This works if you want to call the SAME method in the base class. What if you want to call a DIFFERENT method in the base class?