# How can I override a parent method in coffeescript while still being able to call the parent

Tags: coffeescript

I have two coffeescript classes something like this.  In the base view model I have a method that I want to override in the child that inherits from the base view model.

```
class exports.BaseViewModel
    constructor: () ->

    someBaseMethod: =>
        console.log "I'm doing the base stuff"

class ChildViewModel extends BaseViewModel
    constructor: () ->

    someBaseMethod: =>
        @doSomethingFirst()
        super @someBaseMethod()
```

This isn't working as is because the line `super @someBaseMethod()` calls itself creating an infinite loop.

Is it possible to achieve what I want here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling coffescript super methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520116/calling-coffescript-super-methods)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, call `super` just like it was a function (it represents a reference to the superclass version of the method you're in):

```
class ChildViewModel extends BaseViewModel
  constructor: ->

  someBaseMethod: =>
    @doSomethingFirst()
    super()
```