# In CoffeeScript when trying to call a method (@_methodName) in a class it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use [underscore's debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function in my code, and I'm passing a method of my class as the first parameter, but `_.debounce` is telling me that I'm passing an `undefined` parameter where the function should be.

```
class SomeClass

  click: _.debounce @_save, 600

  _save: =>
    # Save logic
```

On the other hand, If I do it like this, it works, but this solution seems kind of ugly.

```
class SomeClass

  click: _.debounce ( -> 
    @_save()
  ), 600

  _save: =>
    # Save logic
```

When I check the generated JS source of both functions, it seems like both should work fine, don't know if I'm missing something from CoffeeScript here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoffeeScript compiles:

```
click: _.debounce @_save, 600
```

into:

```
SomeClass.prototype.click = _.debounce(SomeClass._save, 600);
```

Notice how `_save` method is a static property of `SomeClass`, i.e. **it is not on the prototype** because in your declaration `@` refers to the class itself, not its instance.

Alternatively you can declare your click function in the constructor:

```
constructor: ->
  @click = _.debounce @_save, 600
```

This will ensure you have a debounced function per instance, and not a shared one.

Comment: if my class extends a parent class, how I can call the parent constructor?

Comment: @gpopoteur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520116/calling-coffescript-super-methods

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should try something like this instead:

```
class SomeClass
  constructor: ->
    @click = _.debounce @_save, 600

  _save: =>
    # ...
```